# jQuery DatePicker - adding class to dates removes the default ones

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When using the jQuery Datepicker I need to add different classes to different dates, but doing so removes the default classes, like `ui-datepicker-current-day` for the currently selected day. How can I use `beforeShowDay` to add a class without removing the default functionality?

At the moment, the datepicked is constructed using

```
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var classString = '';

                if (isDateInArray(date, flexArray)) {
                    classString += 'dp-flex';
                }
                else if (isDateInArray(date, loggedArray)) {
                    classString += 'dp-hasreg';
                }
                else if (isDateInArray(date, childcareArray)) {
                    classString += 'dp-childcare';
                }
                else if (isDateInArray(date, sickArray)) {
                    classString += 'dp-syg';
                }
                else if (isDateInArray(date, vacationArray)) {
                    classString += 'dp-ferie';
                }
                else if (isDateInArray(date, unloggedArray)) {
                    classString += 'dp-manglerreg';
                }
                else {
                    classString += 'dp-freeday';
                }

                return [true, classString];
            },
           ...
        });
```

Comment: `addClass()`? Let's see some code.

Comment: @JasonP: beforeShowDay is used within the construction of the datepicker. I don't see how addClass() fits into this.

Comment: did you try initializing `var classString` with default classes then adding other classes? i.e. instead of `var classString = '';` start with `var classString = 'defalut classes';`

Comment: @th1rdey3: And where would I find the default classes?

Answer (score 1):

By default they do not have any value for their class attribute so you are not removing any default functionality.
The classes specified in beforeShowDay callback do get appended,

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var classString = 'test1';
      classString+=' test2';
      classString+=(' test-'+Date.now());
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {

                return [true,classString];

            }
        });
});
```

this will append all classes *test1 test2 ..* to any existing classes.
http://jsbin.com/uBAbiBu/2/edit

Comment: The current day has the `ui-datepicker-current-day` class.

Comment: The existing classes remain and the classes specified in beforeShowDay are appended, take a look at this example http://jsbin.com/uBAbiBu/1

Comment: That's what I would have expected too, but if I in any way modify the classString, the `ui-datepicker-current-day` disappears from the selected day.

Comment: Actually, I see now that its kind of correct. I see that I get the `ui-datepicker-week-end` on weekend days, but the `ui-datepicker-current-day` is still gone =/

Comment: i have updated my answer please take a look at the example http://jsbin.com/uBAbiBu/2/edit i think everything is fine. The classes remain nothing is gone.

Comment: I agree that it should work like that for me too! Here's a screenshot of how the elements look after I click the 19th: http://imgur.com/QAedWCq and here's the relevant code: http://pastebin.com/8UkHGVrL  The part that handles the `ui-datepicker-current-day` is a workaround, that is applicable in this case, but not in two other datepickers.

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi I placed your code here http://jsbin.com/uBAbiBu/3/edit and everything is fine. What i notice from your comment is that the problem occurs when you click on a day. The beforeShowDay is called before the datepicker is displayed. So the implementation of this callback is not a problem. The issue that you mention i guess it is that both the 18th and 19th are rendered as active, right? Just note that the click you mentioned is associated with the onSelect code. When i click due to the onSelect code it tries to navigate away. So if you comment out that code does it render correctly?